# Where are the cheapest garages and apartments in GTA Online?

Tags: achievements, grand-theft-auto-online

In order to get the achievement "American Dream" you need to own an insured vehicle (which you get free), a garage, and an apartment.

Seeing as many of the garages and apartments are pretty expensive in the beginning, I would like to know what the cheapest ones are and where they are located. The location preferably with a screenshot of the map with the location of the garage or apartement marked.

Comment: Cheapest Garages & Apartments mean many players may have bought it. Higher chance to meet other players & get killed. lol

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a huge list of all the cheapest houses and garages in Grand Theft Auto Online:

Cheapest Garage:

[image: Cheapest Garage]

Building: Unit 124 Popular St
Type: Garage
Features: 2 Car Storage
Price: $25,000
Location: East Los Santos

Cheapest House:

[image: Cheapest House]

Building: 0112 Rockford Dr Apt 13
Type: Apartment
Features: House & 2 Car Garage
Price: $80,000
Location: West Los Santos

The information can be found in-game on your phone using the Internet. Money & Services - Dynasty Real Estate. The guide below has all properties listed in price order to make things a bit simpler.

http://www.gamersheroes.com/2013/10/02/grand-theft-auto-online-complete-properties-price-guide-cheapest-expensive/

Comment: I will mark this one correct, if at least the most cheapest garage and appartement are in the actual answer, due to the fact that the link might get taken down and the answer will be of no use to anybody. Also with a map location I was looking for maybe a map screenshot with an X where the garage or appartement should be and not just "North Los Santos", because that could be anywhere, so I will edit my question in that regard.

Comment: Updated to include the info you suggested. I'm currently working on the image as we speak, hope to have it included later today

Comment: Images added as you requested Strike :D Hope it helps mate.

Comment: Thanks for the images, but same guideline as before: Please make them part of the answer too. If the linked website goes dark the answer will be useless again. Also it might be beneficial to say there is an ingame website which will let you see where the properties are and what they cost (that's what I'm getting from the screenshots). Also, I think I can safely mark this answer as correct, but please put the last finishing touches to it.   :D

Comment: Done and done :D

Comment: Erhm... the garage screenshot points to the wrong one (32k $) instead of the right one (25k $) in the answer and on the website you linked to. You might want to correct both (assuming that you are a collaborator on the linked site).

Comment: Thanks Strike. Updated the articles to reflect your feedback. Updated the comment also :D

Answer (score 4):

The cheapest garage is Unit 124 Popular St. for $25,000 (or free with the Collectors Edition). It's a two-car garage.

Answer (score 3):

The cheapest i've found is $29,500. It's one in a group of four located in la mesa in the central to south eastern area of the city.