# Which property has the most garages for the cheapest price?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Apartments in GTA online have a certain number of garage spaces attached to it.  Which one has the most garage space for the cheapest price?

Comment: Not the same, but related: [Where are the cheapest garages and apartments in GTA V Online?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132992/where-are-the-cheapest-garages-and-apartments-in-gta-v-online)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$200K is actually the cheapest apartment with a 10 car garage. If you're looking for just the garage, there are a couple of cheaper 10 car carages available. Courtesy or reddit user  pvt13krebs, there's a list that lists all the garages:

[Link: List of gta apartments and garages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHkcL.png)

Answer (score 1):

For $200k, you can get an apartment on Del Perro that has a 10 car garage.  I haven't found anything cheaper that comes with a 10 car.